# Angular 6 and AngularFirestore INSERT, UPDATE

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire

In the code below, what I have is button event handler that when called gets a questionId and a userId. It then checks the Answers collection to see if that user has already answered the given question. If so, do an update, if not, do an insert. This code works, almost. It causes an endless loop, when I update?! I'm not sure why? Thoughts?

```
addAnswer(answer: string) {

var questionId = this.selectedQuestion.id;
var userId = this.selectedUser.id;
//FIRST: check to see if this user already answered this question
// if so, do an update, not an add
var answersRef = this.db.collection('Answers', ref => {
    // Compose a query using multiple .where() methods
    return ref
        .where('userId', '==', userId)
        .where('questionId', '==', questionId)
});


answersRef.snapshotChanges().subscribe(
    data => {
        console.log(data);
        //
        if (data.length > 0) {
            //UPDATE as they already have an answer to the question
            console.log('UPDATE');
            data.map( a => {
                console.log(a.payload.doc.id);
                //
                this.db.collection('Answers').doc(a.payload.doc.id).update({
                    answer: answer,
                    date: null,
                    isPublic: true,
                    //questionId: questionId,
                    //userId: userId,
                })
                .then( docRef => {
                    console.log("Document successfully updated!");

                }) 
                .catch( error => {
                    console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
                });
            });
        }
        else {
            //INSERT
            console.log('INSERT');
            this.db.collection('Answers').add({
                answer: answer,
                date: null,
                isPublic: true,
                questionId: questionId,
                userId: userId,
              })
              .then( docRef => {
                console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
              })
              .catch( error => {
                console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
              });
        }

    }
);
```

}

Comment: add / update it outside the snapshot subscription.